# Can I dispose a DataTable and still use its data later?

Tags: ado.net

Noob ADO.NET question: Can I do the following?

1. Retrieve a DataTable somehow.
2. Dispose it.
3. Still use its data. (But not send it back to the database, or request the database to update it.)

I have the following function, which is indirectly called by every `WebMethod` in a Web Service of mine:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string cmdText, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    // Read the connection string from the web.config file.
    Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/WSProveedores");
    ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["..."];

    SqlConnection connection = null;
    SqlCommand command = null;
    SqlParameterCollection parameterCollection = null;
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    DataTable dataTable = null;

    try
    {
        // Open a connection to the database.
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        // Specify the stored procedure call and its parameters.
        command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        parameterCollection = command.Parameters;
        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
            parameterCollection.Add(parameter);

        // Execute the stored procedure and retrieve the results in a table.
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            if (command != null)
            {
                if (dataAdapter != null)
                {
                    // Here the DataTable gets disposed.
                    if (dataTable != null)
                        dataTable.Dispose();
                    dataAdapter.Dispose();
                }

                parameterCollection.Clear();
                command.Dispose();
            }

            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // However, I still return the DataTable
    // as if nothing had happened.
    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is to Dispose anything that implements `IDisposable`, whether it "needs it" or not. Saves you from the times when it "needs it" and you didn't think to Dispose.

Once you've called Dispose on an object, you shouldn't use it anymore. Period. It violates the entire concept of Dispose.

This is why you shouldn't call Dispose on an object that you are returning from a method. Leave it up to the caller to call Dispose when they're done with the object.

---

BTW, your code could be simpler. More like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection))
    {
        //...
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When an `using` clause is inside a `try` block, and an exception occurs, does the disposable object get cleaned up properly?

Comment: @Eduardo: yes. A try block doesn't change what happens inside of it.

Comment: I mean, if an exception happens inside the `using` block, technically, the control flow of the program doesn't reach the point where the disposable object should be disposed.

Comment: @Eduardo: huh? If there's an exception inside of the block, then control flow exits the block. By definition, that  means the Disposable object should be disposed.

Comment: @John: It's actually good to know, but, coming from a C++ background, it's kind of baffling to me how heap-allocated objects can be automatically deallocated without explicitly instructing the program to do so. I mean, we're not even assigning their references to `null`.

Comment: @Eduardo: .NET uses automatic garbage collection, similar to what Java uses. There is no explicit `delete` operator because it's not necessary. `Dispose` has nothing to do with memory management, BTW. It only has to do with resources not managed by .NET - file handles, GDI handles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't have your cake and eat it :)

Close the connection and so on, sure, but why do you need to dispose the table? That's not necessary. Just return it as-is.

Otherwise you'd be in a position where you... copy the table to something else and then return that instead? If you were using a ORM for example and mapping data to objects and then returning the objects this would make sense, but if you're not then just use the table/dataset directly.